# How to get media player in C# to recognise my path?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to get the  Media Player to play my audio files, but it always returns the error "System.UriFormatException", even though I have provided the right path.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private MediaPlayer m_mediaPlayer;

    public void Play(string filename)
    {
        m_mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        m_mediaPlayer.Open(new Uri(filename));
        m_mediaPlayer.Play();
    }

    private void m_btnSound_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Play("Sound.wav");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try specifying the full path to `Sound.wav`

Comment: Try to put the full path of your file like  @"c:\mediafile.wmv"

Comment: Thank you for your fast answers but I meant that it is working properly when i put in the full path. I wanted to know why it does not work when I have the sound in the debug file and then only use the code:
```csharp
Play("Sound.wav");
```
Because as far as I know you do not have to name the full path when the used data file is in the debug file. Right?

Comment: What do you mean by "in the debug file"? An embedded resource? Or you mean it's in the same folder as the executable? The "working folder" (default folder when no path is given) for a running application is not necessarily the same as the folder that the exe is in.